# Invalid regular expression range out of order in character class

Tags: angular

When running an Angular application, I get this error:

> Invalid regular expression: /[^ áš€á Žâ€€-â€Š â€¯âŸã€€]/: Range out of order in character class

The (minified) line of code causing the error is:

```
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be
 * found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license
 */var ec="ngPreserveWhitespaces",tc=new Set(["pre","template","textarea","script","style"]),nc=" \f\n\r\t\váš€á Žâ€€-â€Š\u2028\u2029â€¯âŸã€€\ufeff",rc=new RegExp("[^"+nc+"]"),ic=n.....
```

This code is coming from Angular, so why does it cause a runtime error?

Note: using Angular 6.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was that the javascript file was being downloaded as ASCII. The solution is to tell the browser to interpret the file as UTF-8 instead. There are 2 ways to do this in the HTML file:

Globally set charset to UTF-8:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
```

or use UTF-8 only for the one file:

```
<script src="lib.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I opted for the first option.

Comment: I opted for the second option - I was facing the same issue when using webpack JS bundle.